# Show that $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am trying to prove all of the [properties of inner product spaces listed on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Basic_properties) (using the axioms of an inner product space listed on the same Wikipedia page), and I am stuck on proving the third one:

> - $\langle x,x\rangle = 0$ if and only if $x = \mathbf{0}$.

There are two directions to this proof, and I have already proved the first:

- Suppose $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$. By the contrapositive of the positive definiteness property of inner product spaces, if $\langle x, x \rangle \leq 0$, then $x = \mathbf{0}$, so it follows immediately that $x = \mathbf{0}$.

But I don't know how to prove the other direction: how do we prove that $x = \mathbf{0}$ implies that $\langle x, x \rangle = 0$?

Comment: Linearity in first element suffices, doesn't it?

Comment: That property is part of the definition of what an inner product is (there are *many* notions of inner product).  What, exactly, are you trying to do?  Are you trying to verify that something or another *is* an inner product?  What is the definition of that "something"?

Comment: You are trying to prove that these properties for which potential inner product space? What is the underlying vector space (over what field)? How is the pairing defined?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: I expect they are trying to demonstrate $\langle 0, 0 \rangle = 0$ from the definition in the Wikipedia plot summary linked to in the OP. But I think you make a good point.

Comment: @BrianTung Oh, jeez... the definition on Wikipedia is subtly different that the one I know.  The definition I am familiar with is that $\langle x, x\rangle \ge 0$, with equality only if $x=0$.  This is the problem with *linking* to other places, rather than just copying the definitions over.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I edited my post to clarify which axioms of an inner product space I am using, and what exactly it is that I am trying to prove. Thank you for inviting the extra rigor in my wording!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using linearity and since $0 + 0 = 0$ :
$$\langle 0,x\rangle = \langle 0 + 0,x \rangle = \langle 0,x\rangle + \langle 0,x \rangle \Rightarrow  \langle 0,x \rangle = 0 \ \forall x$$ and in particular, for $x = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x=0$, then $x=0v$ for every $v\in V$. Thus, $\langle x, x\rangle=\langle 0v, x\rangle=0\langle v, x\rangle=0$.